# Functions and Quotes in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, string-formatting

When I type M(google) into the R prompt after defining the below function, I receive an error telling me the site couldn't load.  I assume the problem is that R sees the quotes around the link and tries to access the literal link seen below and not google.

Suppose the function:

```
M <- function(input){
     url<-"http://www.(input).com"
     table<-readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
     }
```

What is this problem called and how do I resolve it?  The typical error is:

```
Error: failed to load HTTP resource
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
library("XML")
M <- function (input) {
  url <- paste0("http://www.", input , ".com")
  table <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(table)
}
```

The `"http://www.(input).com"` is simply a `character`.

Remember also, that your function call should be `M("google")`and not `M(google)`. You need the quotes. By calling `M(google)` you are causing R to search for an object named `google` in the enclosing environment from which the function was called (typically the Global Environment). I have added `return(table)` since I guess you also want your function to return the output.